# Can one component accept another as a Input() in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

### Warning!

Before using technique in the answer, please check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248159/angular-2-can-one-component-have-multiple-templates), which describes error `Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'CD_INIT_VALUE'.` I've also provided a pretty (imo) workaround there.

### Question

I wrote a popup (dialog) component, which creates a small window in the center of the screen with two buttons and close icon. I want to use this component for a few purposes: prompt, alert, confirmation, etc. So I need defferent templates be conditionally included. Am I right that the only good way is this: [to include all code at once and use *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248159/angular-2-can-one-component-have-multiple-templates)? Or may be I should create one component for prompt, one for confirmation? But in second case I will get some lines of code duplicated.

### Tip

You may mant to use this question in cooperation with [Angular 2 @ViewChild in *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif)

Comment: You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` in the modal component and just pass the type of the component you want to get displayed in the modal similar to what I explain in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 where the type is passed to an `@Input()`. You can also use a shared service to notify the modal component to display a component which makes it easier to address it from anywhere within your app.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer may be you convert your comment to answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer assuming you are interested in Angular let me share with you this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11007 and this http://plnkr.co/edit/mZSc40KbgBk2azpPVG3g?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` in the modal component and just pass the type of the component you want to get displayed in the modal similar to what I explain in stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/… where the type is passed to an @Input().
You can also use a shared service to notify the modal component to display a component which makes it easier to address it from anywhere within your app.
See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html