# @ViewChild in *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, viewchild

### Question

What is the most elegant way to get `@ViewChild` after corresponding element in template was shown?

Below is an example. Also [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xAhnVVGckjTHLHXva6wp?p=preview) available.

**Component.template.html:**

```html
<div id="layout" *ngIf="display">
  <div #contentPlaceholder></div>
</div>
```

**Component.component.ts:**

```js
export class AppComponent {

    display = false;
    @ViewChild('contentPlaceholder', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewContainerRef;

    show() {
        this.display = true;
        console.log(this.viewContainerRef); // undefined
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(this.viewContainerRef); // OK
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

I have a component with its contents hidden by default. When someone calls `show()` method it becomes visible. However, before Angular 2 change detection completes, I can not reference to `viewContainerRef`. I usually wrap all required actions into `setTimeout(()=>{},1)` as shown above. Is there a more correct way?

I know there is an option with `ngAfterViewChecked`, but it causes too much useless calls.

### [ANSWER (Plunker)](http://plnkr.co/edit/myu7qXonmpA2hxxU3SLB?p=preview)

Comment: did you try using [hidden] attribute instead of *ngIf? It worked for me for a similar situation.

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Use a setter for the ViewChild:

```js
 private contentPlaceholder: ElementRef;

 @ViewChild('contentPlaceholder') set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if(content) { // initially setter gets called with undefined
        this.contentPlaceholder = content;
    }
 }
```

The setter is called with an element reference once `*ngIf` becomes `true`.

Note, for Angular 8 you have to make sure to set `{ static: false }`, which is a default setting in other Angular versions:

```js
 @ViewChild('contentPlaceholder', { static: false })
```

Note: if contentPlaceholder is a component you can change ElementRef to your component Class:

```js
  private contentPlaceholder: MyCustomComponent;

  @ViewChild('contentPlaceholder') set content(content: MyCustomComponent) {
     if(content) { // initially setter gets called with undefined
          this.contentPlaceholder = content;
     }
  }
```

Comment: note that this setter is called initially with undefined content, so check for null if doing something in the setter

Comment: Good answer, but `contentPlaceholder` is `ElementRef` not `ViewContainerRef`.

Comment: I ran into a related issue recently, it was still passing undefined even after *ngIf was true. That turned out to be caused by not including the Component in my NgModule. For ex I did @ViewChild(MatCheckbox) when MatCheckbox was not registered in NgModule. I'm not sure why the template didn't throw an error when I used <mat-checkbox> in the first place, but it probably would have blown up with AOT compilation anyways.

Comment: Answer also works in conjunction with the fact that `ElementRef` will be `undefined` even inside the `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle event with directives such as `*ngIf` since element references after processed **after** such directives are done with evaluation.

Comment: How do you call the setter?

Comment: @LeandroCusack it gets called automatically when Angular finds ```<div #contentPlaceholder></div>```. Technically you can call it manually like any other setter ```this.content = someElementRef``` but I don't see why you would want to do that.

Comment: Just don't forget to detect changes, in case you're using that child as an input to another child component. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngif-var-template-error

Comment: This doesn't work for me using the AOT compiler: `Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced in decorators because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler in 'ViewChild': 'ViewChild' is not initialized at ../@angular/core/src/metadata/di.ts(360,22).`

Comment: For me it was still calling the function even though the ngif was false, so as a fix I had to do this:
`@ViewChild('geolocalisationOutlet', {read: ViewContainerRef}) set geolocalisation(geolocalisationOutlet: ViewContainerRef) {
        if (geolocalisationOutlet) {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
`

Comment: This works, but where is this in the official documentation?

Comment: The setter name `content` is important or we can rename it?
What if you have many elements like this? You'll see "Duplicate identifier 'content'"

Comment: @zhuhang.jasper the setter name is not important. I had two instances of @ViewChild, and simply named the setters `content1` and `content2` with success.

Comment: Just a helpful note for anyone who comes across this now - you need to have @ViewChild('myComponent', {static: false}) where the key bit is the static: false, which allows it to take different inputs.

Comment: I also had to add {read: ElementRef}, in addition to static: false to my @ViewChild for this to work for a custom component. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921819/angular-nativeelement-is-undefined-on-viewchild

Comment: Good answer, but I was trying to view a child component's child, so that obviously didn't work. Just a reminder to double check, if this answer still does not work for you ;)

Comment: Whatever I do it will not get ViewContainerRef if ngIf is used. set is called but with undefined value, when I remove ngIf, set argument has value.

Comment: Good trick! Will make use of it in some scenarios. Thank you.

Comment: Solved my problem after working on it for 2-3 hours

Answer (score 161):

An alternative to overcome this is running the change detector manually.

You first inject the `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

Then you call it after updating the variable that controls the *ngIf

```
show() {
        this.display = true;
        this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the accepted answer but it was still causing an error because the children were still undefined when I tried to use them sometime after `onInit()`, so I added the `detectChanges` before calling any child function and it fixed it. (I used both the accepted answer and this answer)

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks!

Comment: I had to run the CDR as well, the ViewChild was not updated soon enough when I needed it. This may happen if you rely on the child in the same function as you update the `*ngIf` property. In that case, the changes may not have been detected yet and the ViewChild property may still be undefined.

Comment: Any ideas why I might be getting this error when trying to call detectChanges(): 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

Answer (score 128):

**Angular 8+**

You should add `{ static: false }` as a second option for `@ViewChild`. This causes the query results to be resolved *after* change detection runs, allowing your `@ViewChild` to be updated after the value changes.

Example:

```js
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('contentPlaceholder', { static: false }) contentPlaceholder: ElementRef;

    display = false;

    constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    show() {
        this.display = true;

        // Required to access this.contentPlaceholder below,
        // otherwise contentPlaceholder will be undefined
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

        console.log(this.contentPlaceholder);
    }
}
```

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8ezsn

Comment: Thank you Sviatoslav. Tried everything above but only your solution worked.

Comment: This also worked for me (as did the viewchildren trick). This one is more intuitive and easier for angular 8.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for the latest version.

Comment: I am using `<mat-horizontal-stepper *ngIf="viewMode === DialogModeEnum['New']" linear #stepper`, `@ViewChild('stepper', {static: true}) private stepper: MatStepper;` and `this.changeDetector.detectChanges();` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: i must wait few ms after detectchanges with setTimeout

Comment: The text of the answer is missing the fact that you have to call `detectChanges` which does not seem like something you should do, I would much rather have a setter and not have to inject extra cruft into my component. Not to mention the two comments above saying it doesn't work... so I don't agree that this should be the accepted answer, it's an alternative.

Comment: Probably the best solution for Angular 8+, but `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` is indeed required

Comment: I wonder if there is some better option, because most time we use static:false for the dynamic element, but if my component is static after the ngIf flag is identified, i prefer to delay the value getter, but after it get the value, treat the element as a static one because it won't change again.

Comment: "Starting with version 9, the static flag will default to false." from https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration

Comment: Clean and well understood, arigato sensei...

Answer (score 23):

The answers above did not work for me because in my project, the ngIf is on an input element. I needed access to the nativeElement attribute in order to focus on the input when ngIf is true. There seems to be no nativeElement attribute on ViewContainerRef. Here is what I did (following [@ViewChild documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html)):

```
<button (click)='showAsset()'>Add Asset</button>
<div *ngIf='showAssetInput'>
    <input #assetInput />
</div>

...

private assetInputElRef:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('assetInput') set assetInput(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.assetInputElRef = elRef;
}

...

showAsset() {
    this.showAssetInput = true;
    setTimeout(() => { this.assetInputElRef.nativeElement.focus(); });
}
```

I used setTimeout before focusing because the ViewChild takes a sec to be assigned. Otherwise it would be undefined.

Comment: A setTimeout() of 0 worked for me. My element hidden by my ngIf was correctly bound after a setTimeout, without the need for the set assetInput() function in the middle.

Comment: You can detectChanges in showAsset() and not have to use the timeout.

Comment: How's this an answer? The OP already mentioned using a `setTimeout`? `I usually wrap all required actions into setTimeout(()=>{},1) as shown above. Is there a more correct way?`

Answer (score 19):

As was mention by others, the fastest and quickest solution is to use `[style.display]="condition ? '' : 'none'"` or `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`. Taking this approach the component will be created but not visible, therefore you have access to it. This might not be the most efficient way.

Comment: you have to note that using "[hidden]" may not work if the element is not of "display: block". better use [style.display]="condition ? '' : 'none'"

Answer (score 14):

This could work but I don't know if it's convenient for your case:

```ts
@ViewChildren('contentPlaceholder', {read: ViewContainerRef}) viewContainerRefs: QueryList;

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.viewContainerRefs.changes.subscribe(item => {
   if(this.viewContainerRefs.toArray().length) {
     // shown
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: Can you please try `ngAfterViewInit()` instead of `ngOnInit()`. I assumed that `viewContainerRefs` is already initialized but doesn't yet contain items. Seems I remembered this wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. `AfterViewInit` actually works. I've removed all my comments in order not to confuse people. Here is a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/myu7qXonmpA2hxxU3SLB?p=preview

Comment: This is actually a good answer. It works and I'm using this now. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me after upgrade from angular 7 to 8. For some reason, the upgrade caused the component to be undefined in afterViewInit even with using static: false per the new ViewChild syntax when the component was wrapped in an ngIf. Also note that the QueryList requires a type now like this QueryList<YourComponentType>;

Comment: Might be the change related to the `const` parameter of `ViewChild`

Answer (score 11):

**Another quick "trick" (easy solution)** is just to use [hidden] tag instead of *ngIf, just important to know that in that case Angular build the object and paint it under class:hidden this is why the ViewChild work without a problem.
**So it's important to keep in mind that you should not use hidden on heavy or expensive items that can cause performance issue**

```
  <div class="addTable" [hidden]="CONDITION">
```

Comment: If that hidden is inside in another if then need to change many things

Answer (score 8):

My goal was to avoid any hacky methods that assume something (e.g. setTimeout) and I ended up implementing the accepted solution with a bit of *RxJS* flavour on top:

```
  private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();
  private tabSetInitialized = new Subject();
  public tabSet: TabsetComponent;
  @ViewChild('tabSet') set setTabSet(tabset: TabsetComponent) {
    if (!!tabSet) {
      this.tabSet = tabSet;
      this.tabSetInitialized.next();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    combineLatest(
      this.route.queryParams,
      this.tabSetInitialized
    ).pipe(
      takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    ).subscribe(([queryParams, isTabSetInitialized]) => {
      let tab = [undefined, 'translate', 'versions'].indexOf(queryParams['view']);
      this.tabSet.tabs[tab > -1 ? tab : 0].active = true;
    });
  }
```

**My scenario:** I wanted to fire an action on a `@ViewChild` element depending on the router `queryParams`. Due to a wrapping `*ngIf` being false until the HTTP request returns the data, the initialization of the `@ViewChild` element happens with a delay.

**How does it work:** `combineLatest` emits a value for the first time only when each of the provided Observables emit the first value since the moment `combineLatest` was subscribed to. My Subject `tabSetInitialized` emits a value when the `@ViewChild` element is being set. Therewith, I delay the execution of the code under `subscribe` until the `*ngIf` turns positive and the `@ViewChild` gets initialized.

Of course don't forget to unsubscribe on ngOnDestroy, I do it using the `ngUnsubscribe` Subject:

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot I've had the same issue, with tabSet & ngIf, your method saved me a lot of time and headache. Cheers m8 ;)

Comment: Had same issue and u saved my day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version, I had a similar issue to this when using the Google Maps JS SDK.

My solution was to extract the `div`and `ViewChild` into it's own child component which when used in the parent component was able to be  hid/displayed using an `*ngIf`.

***Before***

`HomePageComponent` Template

```
<div *ngIf="showMap">
  <div #map id="map" class="map-container"></div>
</div>
```

`HomePageComponent` Component

```
@ViewChild('map') public mapElement: ElementRef; 

public ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
});

private loadMap() {

  const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-1234, 4567);
  const mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
}

public toggleMap() {
  this.showMap = !this.showMap;
 }
```

***After***

`MapComponent` Template

```
 <div>
  <div #map id="map" class="map-container"></div>
</div>
```

`MapComponent` Component

```
@ViewChild('map') public mapElement: ElementRef; 

public ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMap();
});

private loadMap() {

  const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-1234, 4567);
  const mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  };
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
}
```

`HomePageComponent` Template

```
<map *ngIf="showMap"></map>
```

`HomePageComponent` Component

```
public toggleMap() {
  this.showMap = !this.showMap;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It Work for me if i use ChangeDetectorRef in Angular 9

```
@ViewChild('search', {static: false})
public searchElementRef: ElementRef;

constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

//then call this when this.display = true;
show() {
   this.display = true;
   this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure passing the param `{ static: false }` to `@ViewChild` resolve the problem.

**template.html code**

```html
<div *ngIf="showFirtChild">
  <first-child #firstchildComponent ></first-child>
</div>
```

**in .ts file**

```
export class Parent implements {
  private firstChild: FirstchildComponent;

  @ViewChild('firstchildComponent', { static: false }) set content(content: 
  FirstchildComponent) {
     if(content) { 
          this.firstchildComponent = content;
     }
  }

  ShowChild(){
     this.showFirtChild = true;
     if(this.firstchildComponent){
        this.firstchildComponent.YourMethod()
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to load a whole module only when the div existed in the template, meaning the outlet was inside an ngif. This way everytime angular detected the element #geolocalisationOutlet it created the component inside of it. The module only loads once as well.

```
constructor(
    public wlService: WhitelabelService,
    public lmService: LeftMenuService,
    private loader: NgModuleFactoryLoader,
    private injector: Injector
) {
}

@ViewChild('geolocalisationOutlet', {read: ViewContainerRef}) set geolocalisation(geolocalisationOutlet: ViewContainerRef) {
    const path = 'src/app/components/engine/sections/geolocalisation/geolocalisation.module#GeolocalisationModule';
    this.loader.load(path).then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
        const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
        const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver
            .resolveComponentFactory(GeolocalisationComponent);
        if (geolocalisationOutlet && geolocalisationOutlet.length === 0) {
            geolocalisationOutlet.createComponent(compFactory);
        }
    });
}

<div *ngIf="section === 'geolocalisation'" id="geolocalisation">
     <div #geolocalisationOutlet></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think using [defer from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#defer) makes a lot of sense especially in my case where my `@ViewChild()` was inside `async` pipe

Answer (score 1):

*Working on Angular 8 No need to import ChangeDector*

ngIf allows you not to load the element and avoid adding more stress to your application. Here's how I got it running without ChangeDetector

```
elem: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('elemOnHTML', {static: false}) set elemOnHTML(elemOnHTML: ElementRef) {
    if (!!elemOnHTML) {
      this.elem = elemOnHTML;
    }
}
```

Then when I change my ngIf value to be truthy I would use setTimeout like this for it to wait only for the next change cycle:

```
  this.showElem = true;
  console.log(this.elem); // undefined here
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.elem); // back here through ViewChild set
    this.elem.do();
  });
```

This also allowed me to avoid using any additional libraries or imports.

Comment: This solution worked for me. Adding setTimeout as suggested here did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

for **Angular 8** - a mixture of null checking and `@ViewChild` `static: false` hackery

for a paging control waiting for async data

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) set paginator(paginator: MatPaginator) {
  if(!paginator) return;
  paginator.page.pipe(untilDestroyed(this)).subscribe(pageEvent => {
    const updated: TSearchRequest = {
      pageRef: pageEvent.pageIndex,
      pageSize: pageEvent.pageSize
    } as any;
    this.dataGridStateService.alterSearchRequest(updated);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make sur that the **static** option is set to false

```
  @ViewChild('contentPlaceholder', {static: false}) contentPlaceholder: ElementRef;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem myself, with Angular 10.

If I tried to use `[hidden]` or `*ngIf`, then the `@ViewChild` variable was always *undefined*.

```
<p-calendar #calendar *ngIf="bShowCalendar" >
</p-calendar>
```

I fixed it by *not* removing it from the webpage.
I used an `[ngClass]` to make the control have `opacity:0`, and move it completely out of the way.

```
<style>
  .notVisible {
    opacity: 0;
    left: -1000px;
    position: absolute !important;
  }
</style>

<p-calendar #calendar [ngClass]="{'notVisible': bShowCalendar }" >
</p-calendar>
```

Yeah, I know, it's dumb and ugly, but it fixed the problem.

I also had to make the control *static*.  I don't understand why.. but, again, it refused to work without this change:

```
export class DatePickerCellRenderer {
    @ViewChild('calendar', {static: true }) calendar: Calendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a situation to set tabindex on `*ngIf`

html:

```html
<div #countryConditional1 *ngIf="country=='USA'">                        
  <input id="streetNumber" [(ngModel)]="streetNumber" pInputText>
</div>
```

ts:

```js
@ViewChild('countryConditional1') set countryConditional1(element) {
  if (element) {
    const container2 = document.querySelector("#someElement");
    container2.querySelector("span > input").setAttribute("tabindex", "18");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If setter doesn't seem to be working (not being called at all) with `@ViewChild` try `@ContentChild` instead.

Comment: @ContentChild is used for something else entirely.