# Returning a component to the template inside another component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component that is responsible for dynamically creating angular material  cards:

```js
export class DashboardComponent {
  cards = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset).pipe(
    map(({ matches }) => {
      if (matches) {
        return [
          { title: 'Card 1', data: InspectionGraphComponent , cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
        ];
      }

      return [
        { title: 'Card 1', data: InspectionGraphComponent , cols: 2, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Card 2', cols: 1, rows: 1 },
        { title: 'Card 3', cols: 1, rows: 2 },
        { title: 'Card 4', cols: 1, rows: 1 }
      ];
    })
  );
}
```

In my Dashboard template, I am accessing details about these cards and displaying them, such as the title. My dashboard displays the title correctly because it is a simple string.

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <h1 class="mat-h1">Dashboard</h1>
  <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="350px">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards | async" [colspan]="card.cols" [rowspan]="card.rows">
      <mat-card class="dashboard-card">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            {{card.title}}
            <button mat-icon-button class="more-button" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" aria-label="Toggle menu">
              <mat-icon>more_vert</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" xPosition="before">
              <button mat-menu-item>Expand</button>
              <button mat-menu-item>Remove</button>
            </mat-menu>
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
          <div>{{card.data}}</div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

I am trying to display a graph inside of that very first card (InspectionGraphComponent) but it isnt working. This graph is in another component.

How can I display and render a component in my card like I am simply displaying the title?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically adding components in ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274281/dynamically-adding-components-in-ngfor)

Comment: Yes, the basic idea would be to create a special directive that will be able to create components dynamically. And use it on the `<ng-container>` tag.