# Angular Material Stepper - how to dynamically create components to load into steps

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have seen a number of similar posts. I wish to be able to use `@ngFor` to create components to then load into steps of the [Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview)

I have been following an [example of dynamic loading](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1o5zma?file=src/app/hero-job-ad.component.ts), and some other posts (which are incomplete), and come up with the following.

First I have a number of components I want to load into the steps. They are just empty apart from the string (eg "component is working"

eg

```
export class StepPage1Component implements OnInit, StepPage {
      constructor() { }
      ngOnInit() {
      }
}
```

So I have 3 of these.

The "root" component is as follows.

```
export class WizardStepperComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('stepper') private myStepper: MatStepper;
  totalStepsCount: number;

  public steps: StepPage[];

  constructor(private stepsService: StepPagesService) { 
    this.steps = [
      new StepPage1Component,
      new StepPage2Component,
      new StepPage3Component
    ]
  }
```

Markup:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
  <mat-step *ngFor='let step of steps'>
    <app-step-page-wrapper item='step'></app-step-page-wrapper>
  </mat-step>     
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

<!-- second option -->
<div>
  <button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === 0">Back</button>
  <button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button"
    [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === stepper._steps.length-1">Next</button>

  <!-- using totalStepsCount -->
  <!-- <button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button" [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === totalStepsCount-1">Next</button> -->
</div>
```

So in markup above, I have the `ngFor` that I am having problems with.

The wrapper is as follows...

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';
import { directiveDef } from '@angular/core/src/view';
import { PageDirective } from '../page.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-step-page-wrapper',
  template: '<ng-template pageDirective></ng-template>',
})
export class StepPageWrapperComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() item?: any;
  @ViewChild(PageDirective) pageHost: PageDirective;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.item == undefined) {
      console.error('Item undefined');
      return 
    }

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.item);
    const viewContainerRef = this.pageHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}
```

and finally the directive it is using is..

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[pageDirective]'
})
export class PageDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

So, I am trying to use the `StepPageWrapperComponent` to take each component as an input (`item`), and then use the `componentFactoryResolver` to create the conponent and then "attach" it to the directive in the template, ie `pageDirective` in `<ng-template pageDirective></ng-template>`

However, when I run this, I get the following error..

```
        ERROR Error: No component factory found for step. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
        at noComponentFactoryError (core.js:9877)
        at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (core.js:9915)
        at StepPageWrapperComponent.push../src/app/step-page-wrapper/step-page-wrapper.component.ts.StepPageWrapperComponent.ngOnInit (step-page-wrapper.component.ts:21)
        at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:22099)
        at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:23363)
        at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:23325)
        at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:23959)
        at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23919)
        at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (WizardStepperComponent.html:3)
        at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
```

If I put a break point in `StepPageWrapperComponent`, `this.item` just seems to be a string!

[image]

So, this string "step" is meant to be the ngFor variable...

[image]

But it is just coming in as a string, rather than the component.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong here, or even if there is a better way of doing this?

For any more details the source for this sample is can be cloned from https://github.com/pjc2007/wizard-stepper1.git

### Update 30 Aug 19

The reason the input was not working was I forgot the square brackets when passing the variable to the input.. ie I had

```
<app-step-page-wrapper item='step'></app-step-page-wrapper>
```

instead of

```
    <app-step-page-wrapper [item]='step'></app-step-page-wrapper>
```

I now have the component as the input for `StepPageWrapperComponent` as expected.

[image]

So, my problem now is the following error that is thrown  when executing the line `const componentFactory=this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.item)`

```
ngComponent: StepPage1Component {}
message: "No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?"
stack: "Error: No component factory found for [object Object]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?↵    at noComponentFactoryError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:71338:17)↵    at CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:71376:19)↵    at StepPageWrapperComponent.push../src/app/step-page-wrapper/step-page-wrapper.component.ts.StepPageWrapperComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:4200/main.js:244:66)↵    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83560:19)↵    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84824:20)↵    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:84786:16)↵    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85420:38)↵    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85380:13)↵    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/WizardStepperComponent.ngfactory.js:16:5)↵    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85372:21)"
__proto__: Object
```

I **do** have this as an entryComponent

ie

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WizardStepperComponent,
    StepPage1Component,
    StepPage2Component,
    StepPage3Component,
    PageDirective,
    StepPageWrapperComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [
    StepPage1Component,
    StepPage2Component,
    StepPage3Component,
    StepPageWrapperComponent
  ]
```

### Update 30 Aug 19

Stepping into `this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory`, I see the following...

[image]

So the component seems to be in the map, but the map.get is returning undefined?

Comment: The method described above is wonderful, I was struggling with building a Modular Stepper as the steps need to be defined in the HTML or won't render with simple injection via Comp Factory. This set me in the right direction. Further more, I added `@Output()` to my "step-wrapper" which allows you to bubble up the stepper functions. (I happened to already have built a dynamic Step Heading/Sub Head and Next/Back button component with alternative button options that also wraps my custom component within the step. Allows for granular step validation/customization). Huge thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the component seems to be in the map, but the map.get is returning
>   undefined?

Yes, it's misleading. You're passing instance of class not class itself.

Consider the following example:

```
class Test {}
console.log(Test);       // class Test {}
console.log(new Test()); // Test {}
```

As you can see the output is quite similar but they are two different things.

So the solution is to pass **component Type** instead of component instance:

```
this.steps = [
  StepPage1Component,
  StepPage2Component,
  StepPage3Component
]
```

Comment: thankyou so much! I really did not even realised I had "newed" the components (I never meant to)!  Anyway that was the only problem, it now works! Cheers!