# Angular, Ionic2 Configure @ViewChild every time it is initialized

Tags: angular, ionic2

I create `Slides` based on a condition. When the condition is true the `Slides` component is initialized.

```
<ion-slides *ngIf="condition === true">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let question of questions">
    // slide content
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Addionally I disable swipe by setting `onlyExternal = true`. Since this is not an input property I have to set the value in the parent component's `ngAfterViewInit` method.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component{
  ...
}
export class QuizPage implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
  ...
  ngAfterViewInit {
    this.slides.onlyExternal = true;
  }
  ...
}
```

When the view condition changes the `Slides`-component gets destroyed and looses the `onlyExternal` setting. It gets initialized again when the condition is fulfilled, but `ngAfterViewInit` is only called once, when the parent component is initialized. Which means the `onlyExternal` setting is not set.

Currently I use `ngAfterViewChecked`, but it gets called quite often, I was wondering if there is a better way to solve this problem.

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  if(this.slides) {
    this.slides.onlyExternal = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the condition checked?

Comment: @GabrielBarreto what do you mean and why does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution on another question: [angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095677/1244727)

A setter has to be used on the `@ViewChild`. That one will only called once, when the `ngIf` condition changes.

```
export class QuizPage {
  private slides: Slides;
  @ViewChild(Slides) set slidesViewChold(slides: Slides) {
    if(slides) {
      slides.onlyExternal = true;
    }
    this.slides = slides;
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User ViewChildren and subscribe to change notification.

Here is an example
https://plnkr.co/edit/jZBWR6Y4afqhV9g020k2

```
  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <div>
        <button (click)="toggleHello()">Toggle Hello</button>
        <h2 #vc *ngIf="show">Hello {{name}}</h2>
      </div>
    `,
  })
  export class App {
    show = true;
    @ViewChildren('vc') h2: QueryList<ElementRef>;

    name:string;
    constructor() {
      this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }

    toggleHello() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.setAttr();
      this.h2.changes.subscribe(()=> {
        this.setAttr();
      }
    }

    setAttr() {
      if(this.show) {
           this.h2.toArray()[0].nativeElement.style['color']= 'blue';
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: This usually works, but not when inside an `*ngIf` block. When the if-condition is not fulfilled the component inside the if gets destroyed. Therefore @ViewChildren is `undefined`. When it is available again the subscription is not active any more.

Comment: i am not sure that i understood you. i use ngIf with ViewChildren in this example. Please show me you html structure to help.

Comment: Everything is included in my question.
`<ion-slides *ngIf="condition === true">...</ion-slides>` is the component that I access with `@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;`.
When the `condition` is `false` `@ViewChild(Slides)` is `undefined`. Therefore `subscribe` does not work.

Comment: try to use @ViewChild with descendants: true and put ViewChild on top

Comment: I could not find a `descendants: true` setting for `@ViewChild`