# Ionic 2: Lifecycle hook firing before page has loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using a package for my layout and I need to javascript call to fire after the elements have all loaded on the page, but I cannot get it to work.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.graphs = [];
  // console.log("View Entering", this.iter);
  this.setCurrentPosition();

  this.clientService.clientStream$.subscribe(
    client => {
      this.client = client;  
      this.isLoading = false;
      this.setupGrid();
    }
  )
}

setupGrid() {
  var elem = document.querySelector('.pckry-grid');

  // Prints "setting up grid, null"
  console.log("setting up grid", elem)

  var pckry = new Packery( elem, {
    itemSelector: ".grid-item"
  });
}
```

Here's the view:

```
<div class="pckry-grid" *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <div class="grid-item g-col-12">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item g-col-12">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item g-col-12">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item g-col-12">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a different hook I can use to prevent the `setupGrid()` function from calling before the elements load?

Comment: The best thing is to avoid manipulate the DOM directly. Use Angular's ViewChild. Here is an example, using ViewChild and ngIf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif

Comment: hmm.. I'm trying to implement it but can't make it work.  Am I supposed to use the `@Viewchild` in lieu of the `*ngIf="!isLoading`.  Would you mind converting my html to work with that response?

Comment: That doesn't really help me

Comment: You should use ViewChild to get an element, and then use its reference to pass to this new Packery( elem ) - in this case, instead of accessing the DOM via querySelector you would follow 'the Angular way' to get access to elements from the view.