# How do you get the selected tab from a bootstrap tabset in Angular4?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have a set of tabs that I create dynamically, dependent on my input data. And what I want to do is to be able to figure out which tab is currently selected. In the example code below, I have a tab control and beneath all this, I have a button that when clicked will delete the selected tab. I've tried to keep this relatively simple and it might seem contrived, but I hope it does to illustrate what I mean.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <ngb-tabset *ngIf="selectedInfo" type="groups" >
    <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of selectedInfo.groups" title={{tab.name}} >
        // some stuff in the tabs
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</div>

<div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary float-left" (click)="deleteTab()" > Delete Tab </button>
</div>


export class MyTabs implements OnInit {

  selectedIfno: MyInfoClass;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // init data

  }

  deleteTab() {


  }

}
```

So let's say I want to delete the currently selected tab. How do I know what tab is currently selected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the active tab id (`activeId`) for [NgbTabset](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api) using Angular `@ViewChild()` to retrieve an instance of the the `NgbTabset` from the HTML. You'd then have access to the `activeId` in the class methods. Considering you are us `*ngIf` you may need to create a setter for `@ViewChild()` described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif). I've updated the example to use the setter.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset" *ngIf="selectedInfo" type="groups">
    <ngb-tab *ngFor="let tab of selectedInfo.groups" title={{tab.name}} >
        // some stuff in the tabs
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbTabset } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

export class MyTabs implements OnInit {
  private tabSet: ViewContainerRef;

  @ViewChild(NgbTabset) set content(content: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.tabSet = content;
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.tabSet.activeId);
  }

  deleteTab() {
    // currently selected tab id
    console.log(this.tabSet.activeId);
  }
}
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IjDOUfoenwYdvW136SPY?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

Comment: i'm unable to do the following:

this.tabSet = content

in the @ViewChild part.... not sure why at the minute, but i can see how all this should be working.

Comment: You are getting an error? The `*ngIf` may be preventing `@ViewChild()` from finding the element on load.

Comment: Yes, i get an error at compile time: 
`Type 'ViewContainerRef' is not assignable to type 'NgbTabset'.
  Property 'tabs' is missing in type 'ViewContainerRef'.`

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: ` @ViewChild(NgbTabset) set content(content: ViewContainerRef) {
    this.tabSet = content;
  };`

It is taken precisely the same as above.

Comment: Sorry, change to private tabSet: ViewContainerRef. Or have both be the NgbTabset. Typing error.

Answer (score 15):

I would suggest listening to the `tabChange` change event - this would allow you to "intercept" all the cases where the active page changes and store info about the currently selected tab. Here is the sketch of the idea:

`<ngb-tabset [activeId]="activeTab" (tabChange)="activeTab = $event.nextId">
  ...
</ngb-tabset>`

And a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4vRDHgWMhcvafXhQkxEO?p=preview

While typing the answer I've realized that keeping track of the active tab *yourself* might be a bit of pain and we could add this functionality to the tabset itself. Feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues