# How to load the tabs programmatically in angular 6 of bootstrap ngb-tabset

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular-bootstrap

I want to load the tabs programmatically as I want using angular 6 typescript. Currently it load when I click to tabs. I, want to load through code. Here is the sample code I tried but still it load on click of tab.

```
<ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset" [activeId]="activeIdString" (tabChange)="tabChangeEvent($event)">
  <ngb-tab title="Workforce Plan-Headcount" id="wf1">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-workforce-plan-headcount></app-workforce-plan-headcount>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Workforce Plan-Cost" id="wf2">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-workforce-plan-cost></app-workforce-plan-cost>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Current Vacancies" id="wf3">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-current-vacancies></app-current-vacancies>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Data Entry" id="wf4">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-data-entry></app-data-entry>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

TS file

```
activeIdString: string;
    tabChangeEvent(evt: any) {
            this.activeIdString = "wf3";
            console.log(this.activeIdString); 
          }
```

I tried this code it load the third third tab on first load. Then it doesn't load the third tab. Is there any best way to load the tabs programmatically.

[How do you get the selected tab from a bootstrap tabset in Angular4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45311454/how-do-you-get-the-selected-tab-from-a-bootstrap-tabset-in-angular4)

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1682

http://plnkr.co/edit/IjDOUfoenwYdvW136SPY?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

This is the working solution for me might be useful to someone else

```
<ngb-tabset #t="ngbTabset" (tabChange)="beforeChange($event)">
  <ngb-tab title="Workforce Plan-Headcount" id="wf1">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-workforce-plan-headcount></app-workforce-plan-headcount>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Workforce Plan-Cost" id="wf2">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-workforce-plan-cost></app-workforce-plan-cost>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Current Vacancies" id="wf3">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-current-vacancies></app-current-vacancies>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Data Entry" id="wf4">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <app-data-entry></app-data-entry>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

**component.ts file**

```
public beforeChange($event: NgbTabChangeEvent) {
        if (condition) {
        // prevent from loading
            $event.preventDefault();   
        }
    else{
        this.t.select($event.nextId);
    }
    }
```