# Wait for an event before load a ionic3 deeplinked page

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have an Ionic3/Angular4 app, the data is source depending on current logged user, so I have to wait the user data event to be fired to setup the data connection. (I use firebase to manage the user auth).

In the main component I have this:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async data => {
      if (data && !data.isAnonymous) {    
        await this.userService.initSettingsAsync(data.uid);
      }
      else {
        this.nav.setRoot('LoginPage');
      }
    });
  }
```

My page is this:

```
@IonicPage({
  segment: 'customers/:customerId',
  defaultHistory: ['CustomersPage'],
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-customer-detail',
  templateUrl: 'customer-detail.html',
})
export class CustomerDetailPage {
  customerId: string;
  customer: Customer;

  constructor(public navParams: NavParams, private customerService: CustomerService) {
    this.customerId = navParams.get("customerId");
  }

  async ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CustomerDetailPage');
    this.customer = await this.customerService.get(this.customerId);
  }
}
```

`this.customerService.get(this.customerId)` MUST execute AFTER `this.userService.initSettingsAsync(data.uid)` promise get resolved, otherwise userService doesn't know where to get the datas.

When the page is loaded by deeplink it get initialized BEFORE the authState event fire.

How can I handle this in a smart way? I mean, I don't like to put the user stuff on every page that needs data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was enough to add the `ion-nav` when the init is done. Super easy ;)
Hope this help.

app.html:

```
<ion-nav *ngIf="initialized" [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  async ngOnInit() {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(async data => {
      if (data && !data.isAnonymous) {    
        await this.userService.initSettingsAsync(data.uid);
        this.initialized = true;
      }
      else {
        this.initialized = true;
        setTimeout(() => this.openPage('LoginPage'));
      }
    });
  }
```

Because 'nav' is added to the view after the initialization, there is a little trick needed ([@ViewChild in *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif)):

```
  private nav: Nav;
  @ViewChild(Nav) set contnav(nav: Nav) {
    this.nav = nav;
  }
```