# Get children of parent element after ngIf (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, selector

I am trying to grab all the `input` elements that only exist after a boolean becomes true. So the `div` is wrapped around an `*ngIf`. I tried grabbing the elements using plain JavaScript, but it keeps returning empty. Here is my code:

**test.component.html**

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="toggleTest($event)">
    Test check box
</mat-checkbox>

<div class="form-area" *ngIf="isTestChecked">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

**test.component.ts**

```
isTestChecked = false;

toggleTest(event: any) {
    this.isTestChecked = event.checked;

    if (this.isTestChecked === true) {
        const children = document.querySelectorAll('.form-area input');
        console.log(children);
    }
}
```

So the `console.log` always prints an empty array. However, if I manually type the query selector in the browser console after setting the boolean to true, then it returns both of the `input` elements.

What am I doing wrong? How come it won't get the input elements after they become added to the DOM? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not access the DOM this way. The Angular way is using [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef).

Take a look, too, at those threads that explain how to use:
[Angular 2 @ViewChild in *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif)

```
private contentPlaceholder: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('contentPlaceholder') set content(content: ElementRef) {
   this.contentPlaceholder = content;
}

<div #contentPlaceholder *ngIf="isTestChecked">
    <input type="number">
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular updates the DOM asynchronously, so you can't access the updated DOM elements in the same event loop. If you really need to manipulate the DOM directly, try add a timeout before the query selection.

```
this.isTestChecked = event.checked;

setTimeout(() => {
    if (this.isTestChecked === true) {
        const children = document.querySelectorAll('.form-area input');
        console.log(children);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as well. However, I didn't want to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: This is not the `Angular way` (using document.querySelectorAll). Plus, you can'ct rely on setTImeout, there is no guarantee the DOM will be rendered when the setTImeout callback is called.

Comment: Yea, that was my main reason of not wanting to use it. Depending on the connection or some other reason, it could not be fully rendered.