# Angular Material Table Sorting - Data Doesn't sort when inside a *ngIf condition

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have a Angular Material Table.  When I surround html for the table with a `<div *ngIf="true">` the table renders but the data no longer sorts when clicking on the header column.

Taking the example from: https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting

And modifying it, just by adding the `<div *ngIf="true"> ... </div>` demonstrates this behavior.  Example is at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quzvjv

Comment: Submitted an issue with Angular Material project - https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14843

Comment: Lol, check the answer

Answer (score 8):

Base on the solution [Angular 5 Material Data Table sorting not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51080143/angular-5-material-data-table-sorting-not-working)

In Angular 8, the `@ViewChild` decorator need a second argument `{static: true|false}`

In order to catch `MatSort` component after DOM rendered, set `{static:false}`:

```
export class TableSortingExample{

    sort;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) set content(content: ElementRef) {
        this.sort = content;
        if (this.sort){
           this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        }
    }
}
```

When set `{static : true}`, Angular Compiler consider this `@ViewChild` element is static, so it only obtain the element one time at `ngOnInit()`. Even if `*ngIf` triggered still can't catch the `MatSort` component.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56359612/11777581 by @PierreDuc

Comment: Thanks for this simple explanation - helped me out :)

Answer (score 4):

Do the console log in `ngOnInit` of `this.sort`

Angular didn't catch `MatSort` component as on init phase NgIf didn't process the template.

Change `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Danil, your suggestion worked, but only when the *ngIf evaluated to true when the view of initialized.

The solution I am now using is:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) set content(sort: MatSort) {
    this.dataSource.sort = sort;
}
```

This was based on information from: [Angular 2 @ViewChild in *ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif)

Full working solution at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-quzvjv-jzdbb6

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 8, We can easily achieve multiple/single material table sorting and paging inside *ngIf. In the below example I am using "ng-template" in order to show/hide the table using *ngIf else.

My Sample *ngIf format

```
   <div *ngIf="!isDataLoadedFromApi; else loadTransactions">No data to display</div>
```

Below tables are in the same form

Table-1

```
<ng-template #loadCases>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="snowDataSource" #snowSort="matSort" matSort class="mat-elevation-z3 snow-table">
    <mat-paginator class="mat-elevation-z3" #snowPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator></ng-template>
```

Table-2

```
<ng-template #loadTransactions>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="transactionDataSource" #transactionSort="matSort" matSort
    class="mat-elevation-z3 transaction-table">
    <mat-paginator class="mat-elevation-z3" #transactionPaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 10, 20]"
        showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator></ng-template>
```

Check the "#transactionSort="matSort" and #transactionPaginator in Table-2.
Also "#snowSort="matSort" and #snowPaginator in Table-1

In the TS file configure view child and other settings like below. That's it.

```
@ViewChild('snowSort', { static: false }) set matSnowSort(snowSort: MatSort) {
this.snowSort = snowSort;
if (this.snowDataSource !== null && this.snowDataSource !== undefined) {
    this.snowDataSource.sort = this.snowSort;
}}

@ViewChild('snowPaginator', { static: false }) set matSnowPaginator(snowPaginator: MatPaginator) {
this.snowPaginator = snowPaginator;
if (this.snowDataSource !== null && this.snowDataSource !== undefined) {
    this.snowDataSource.paginator = this.snowPaginator;
}}

@ViewChild('transactionSort', { static: false }) set matTransactionSort(transactionSort: MatSort) {
this.transactionSort = transactionSort;
if (this.transactionDataSource !== null && this.transactionDataSource !== undefined) {
    this.transactionDataSource.sort = this.transactionSort;
}}

@ViewChild('transactionPaginator', { static: false }) set matTransactionPaginator(transactionPaginator: MatPaginator) {
this.transactionPaginator = transactionPaginator;
if (this.transactionDataSource !== null && this.transactionDataSource !== undefined) {
    this.transactionDataSource.paginator = this.transactionPaginator;
}}

private transactionSort: MatSort;
private transactionPaginator: MatPaginator;
private snowSort: MatSort;
private snowPaginator: MatPaginator;
payIdTransactions: TLItem[];
snowCases: Cases[];
transactionDataSource: MatTableDataSource<TLItem>;
snowDataSource: MatTableDataSource<Cases>;

private getTransactions(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.payIdTransactions = results.getTransactionsResponse.TLItems.TLItem;
    this.transactionDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.payIdTransactions);
}
private getSnowCases(startDate: string, endDate: string) {
    this.snowCases = results.getCasesResponse.cases;
    this.snowDataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.snowCases);
}
```