# Undefined ViewChild in ngIf

Tags: angular

How can you focus on element inside ngIf?

This ngIf is true when the page loads but it still gets an undefined error:

```
@ViewChild("currentDaySpentInput") currentDaySpentInput: ElementRef;  
// ...
<div class="spending-input" *ngIf="!spentInputComplete">
    <label>How much did you spend today?</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="currentDay.spent" (keyup)="onKey($event)" #currentDaySpentInput>
</div>
```

focus element

```
ngOnOnit() {
    this.currentDaySpentInput.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

I tried using the setter suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif) but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for debugging purpose

Comment: Can you see anything from this code that could be causing the error or is it something else?

Comment: Got it posting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewChild is available after AfterViewInit hook and not on Onit that's why you are getting the error. (https://alligator.io/angular/viewchild-access-component/)

```
@ViewChild("currentDaySpentInput") currentDaySpentInput: ElementRef; 
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.currentDaySpentInput.nativeElement.focus()); // mayo
  }
```

It should fix this issue if this doesn't fix the issue will have to see the code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you got `undefined` at startup because the template is not yet rendered and your `ViewChild` cannot detect its attachment to view

To solve it use `AfterViewInit` in here your `@ViewChild` will be resolved, and put your checking in the override method

```
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild() currentDaySpentInput: any;
   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // put your logic here
    console.log(this.currentDaySpentInput.nativeElement);
  }
}
```