# Angular 6, @ViewChild, *ngIf , get input element value before the input element hide

Tags: angular

The [set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/angular-2-viewchild-in-ngif) method can be operating element when the element is show(*ngIf = true).

But, when the input element is hide before, I went to get the input element value, the value will be return back server.

For example:

html, set `#namePlaceholder` input element:

```
    <input *ngIf="editNameActive" type="text" value="{{value}}" #namePlaceholder>
    <div (click)="editName()"></div>
```

component:

`editNameActive` control show or hide input element.

```
editNameActive: boolean = false;
editName(){
    this.editNameActive = this.editNameActive? false:true;
  }
```

set `ElementRef`, input element focus, when the element is show. Get input element value, when It's hide(not work).

```
private namePlaceholder: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('namePlaceholder') set name(name: ElementRef){
    this.namePlaceholder = name;
    if(this.editNameActive) {
      this.namePlaceholder.nativeElement.focus();
    }else{
      //nativeElement' is undefined
      console.log(this.namePlaceholder.nativeElement.value);
    }
  }
```

I also try to get value in `editName()` before the status change:

```
editName(){
 if(this.editNameActive){
    console.log(this.namePlaceholder.nativeElement.value);
    this.editNameActive = false;
 }
}
```

But `namePlaceholder` work in `name()` only.

Comment: instead of `*ngIf="editNameActive"` try to use `[hidden]="editNameActive"`

Comment: User [hidden] insted *ngIf

Comment: @Gopard @PierreDuc, Wow, is work, `[hidden]` is new method? What is the difference between  `[hidden]` and `*ngIf`.

Comment: ngIf removes the element from dom while hidden just hides it (it's still present in DOM)

Comment: But the `.foucs()` still work only `set` function, not work in `editName()`. Although there is no error message, it has no effect.