# PrimeNg: ViewChildren QueryList is always empty

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using an primeng Datable inside an `ngIf`. Each time `ngIf` condition changes, I need to get access to embedded `DataTable`:

```
<div *ngIf="rowVisible">
    <p-table ...>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

My component code is:

```
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html',
})
export class SearchComponent {
    @ViewChildren(DataTable) public dataTable: QueryList<DataTable>;

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void
    {
        this.dataTable.changes.subscribe((comps: QueryList<DataTable>) =>
        {
            if (comps.length > 0) {
                comps.first.reset();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, each time `dataTable` observable changes, `comps.length` is `0`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@ViewChild in \*ngIf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/viewchild-in-ngif)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="rowVisible">
    <p-table #dataTable >
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Setter for ViewChild():

```
 private dataTableRef: ElementRef;

 @ViewChild('dataTable') set dataTableContent(dataTableContent: ElementRef) {
    this.dataTableRef= content;
 }
```