# Wait until component is not null using RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I use component on my html template with quite complicated `*ngIf` condition

```
<my-component #myComponent *ngIf="..."></my-component>
```

and in .ts file

```
@ViewChild('myComponent') public myComponent: MyComponent;
```

After 'click' on button I send request, show/hide some stuff... on ma page - and after that  `*ngIf` in my component should be set to `true`. When `this.myComponent` is not null I can call `init(data)` function inside it. I try to use rxjs for "wait" when this component is not null (setTimeout approach fails sometimes) as follows

```js
let checking = true;

let data = await this.loadData();

interval(100).pipe(takeWhile(()=> checking)).subscribe( _ => { 
  if(this.myComponent) { 
    this.myComponent.init(data)
    checking = false;
  }
})

// ... (stuff which magic which makes that this.myComponent is not null)
```

But this code is quite not nice - it checks variable value every 100ms, the code is also quite long and complicated. Is there a more smart solution which e.g. which trigger code exactly only when `this.myComponent` change value from null (without pinging it every 100ms)?

### Update

I forgot to mention than above `interval...` code is inside some async callback so actually I need to wait when `data` is ready and `myComponent` is not null ( I update above code too)

Comment: @Juan no - it is different qestion

Comment: I think you are looking for setter for `ViewChild`. You need not use `interval` to watch for the component reference becomes defined. You should refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41095677/2216584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an EventEmitter on the child component and listen for that:

On the child component, which you send in its `ngOnInit` function or whenever you're ready for it:

```
@Output() loaded = new EventEmitter<void>();
```

```
await this.getSomeDataFromSomeWhere();
this.loaded.emit();
```

In the parent component HTML:

```
<my-component #myComponent *ngIf="..." (loaded)="myComponent.init(data)"></my-component>
```

Comment: this is quite clever approach - however on my-component I do ngOnInit() { loaded.emit() } - and in parent html (load)=initMyComponent() and in .ts initMyComponent() { this.myComponent.init(this.data) } - however the data is inside quite nested async code - so actually I must wait for it too. But I give +1 - thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should move the call `this.myComponent.init(data)` inside of `ngOnInit` within `MyComponent`.  Use an `@Input()` variable to initialize the component with Data.

```
<my-component #myComponent *ngIf="..." [data]="data"></my-component>
```

And leverage `ngOnInit` inside of MyComponent to do the initialization:

```
@NgComponent({
  selector: 'my-component'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input()
   data: Data;

   ngOnInit() {
      if(this.data) {
         this.init(data);
      }
   }
   init(data: Data) {
      ...
   }
}
```

`ngOnInit` is guaranteed to be called once per compoonent lifetime.  And `ngIf` will destroy/create the component each time boolean expression is toggled.

Comment: this is quite clever approach :) - however the `data` is inside quite nested async code - so actually I must wait for it too ( I update question) - but I give +1 - thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify checking by use [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) and [take(1)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) (which auto-unsubscribe after take first value)

```js
interval(200).pipe(filter(_ => this.myComponent), take(1)).subscribe(_ => {
  // ... this code will run once when this.myComponent is not null
})
```

```js
const { interval } = rxjs;
const { filter, take } = rxjs.operators;

this.myComponent = null;

setTimeout(()=> myComponent = "init", 1000)

interval(200).pipe(filter(_ => this.myComponent), take(1)).subscribe(_ => {
  console.log('My component is ready!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```