# How to subscribe to a Subject on a conditional ViewChild?

Tags: angular

How do you bind to an `EventEmiter` or `Subject` in a child component when that component is contained within an `*ngIf` ?

I've got a component as a `@ViewChild()` inside an `*ngIf`

```
@ViewChild('foo')
foo: FooComponent;
```

```
<div *ngIf="someToggle">
   <app-foo #foo/>
</div>
```

My `FooComponent` has a `Subject` to notify the parent component when something changes:

```
export class FooComponent
{
    @Output()
    somethingChanged = new Subject();
}
```

Now, in my parent component, when I try to subscribe to the `somethingChanged` subject I get an error because `this.foo` is undefined. In the example below there are two places I could subscribe, in the `ngAfterViewInit` which would be the place to do it if the child component wasn't in an `*ngIf`, but it is so it's undefined at this point.

The second place to subscribe is in my `showTheFoo()` method which flips the switch to show the component, but the viewChild is still undefined immediately after that because angular hasn't processed the change yet, so how do I subscribe after the change has been processed and the component is added to the DOM?

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit
{
    @ViewChild('foo')
    foo: FooComponent;

    someToggle = false;


    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // this.foo === undefined.
        // this makes sense because it's hidden
    }

    showTheFoo()
    {
        this.someToggle = true;
        
        // this.foo is still undefined.
        // this also makes sense, because although we've flipped the switch
        // angular hasn't processed the change, 
        // but how do I subscribe after it's been shown?
        this.foo.somethingChanged.subscribe(()=>{});

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/viewchild-in-ngif

Comment: @MikeOne I've tried that and the outcome is the same. I did think about putting the subscription in the setter but that seemed hacky and un-angular. I think Michael D's answer below is the way to go but I'll confirm that shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's better to use [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) instead of a `Subject` here. It's an Angular specific [extension](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.1.0/packages/core/src/event_emitter.ts#L64) of the RxJS `Subject`, so you aren't very far from what you're attempting now.

With `EventEmitter` you could `emit` instead of using `next` and capture the events similar to JS event binding. If you don't need the reference to the child element from the DOM for anything else, then the `@ViewChild` could be ignored.

Try the following

**Child controller (*.ts)**

```js
export class FooComponent {
    @Output()
    somethingChanged = new EventEmitter<any>();

    someFunction() {
        this.somethingChanged.emit('some value');
    }
}
```

**Parent template (*.html)**

```html
<div *ngIf="someToggle">
   <app-foo (somethingChanged)="onSomethingChanged($event)"><app-foo/>
</div>
```

**Parent controller (*.ts)**

```js
showTheFoo() {    
    this.someToggle = true;
}

onSomethingChanged(data: any) {
    console.log(data);    // <-- data from the child component
}
```

Comment: ahhh, nice! I was aware of EventEmitter but didn't realise theimplication.