# Angular material datatable paginator returns undefined when using Akita Entity Store plugin

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-akita

I have been stuck with this for two days and I hope someone can point me to a solution. I have an Angular application using Akita for state management and one of the components is tasked with loading a list of customers. I have placed the important bits of my code below.

```
// customers.component.ts
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    
    // Constructor and other definitions are here

    customers$: Observable<Customer[]>;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) private _paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) private _sort: MatSort;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.customerService.get().subscribe();

        this.customers$ = this._customersQuery.customers$;
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this._sort && this._paginator) {
            // Code here is never executed
        }
    }
}

// customer.service.ts
export class CustomerService extends NgEntityService<CustomerState> {
    
    // Constructor is here
    
    get() {
        return this.http.get<Customer[]>('/api/customers').pipe(
            tap(entities => {
                this.CustomerStore.set(entities);
            })
        );
    }
}

// customer.query.ts
export class CustomerQuery extends QueryEntity<CustomerState> {

    public customers$: Observable<Customer[]> = this.selectAll();

    constructor(protected store: CustomerStore) {
        super(store);
    }

}

// customer.component.html
<ng-container *ngIf="(customers$ | async) as customers">
    <ng-container *ngIf="customers.length > 0; else noCustomers">
        // The table goes here
        <mat-paginator>
            // Paginator options go here
        </mat-paginator>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noCustomers><p>No Customers</p></ng-template>
```

No matter what I do, I always get an `undefined` Paginator instance. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element that you are using `ViewChild` on is in an `ngIf`:

```js
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) private _paginator: MatPaginator;
```

The paginator you are trying to bind to isn't in the DOM when the component is initialized, because it's hidden by the `ngIf`, therefore the binding doesn't occur.

[This is a long discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/viewchild-in-ngif) on how to get around this issue.
The TLDR solution is to use bind to the native HTML `hidden` property and flip your `ngIf` logic. That's not so simple with your code because of the nesting of `ngIf`s and using `ng-container`s, not `div`s.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I got a solution from the link. Thank you!