# Angular12 @ViewChild within two ngIf

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm having problems using @ViewChild because it is nested within two different ngIf.

My template looks something like this:

```html
<div *ngIf="model">
  <div *ngIf="otherModel">
    <myComponent #myComponent></myComponent>
  </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!model">
</div>
```

In template I use my ViewChild like:

```js
    @ViewChild("myComponent", {static: false}) myComponent: MyComponent;
```

Now my problem is that my ViewChild always results as undefined. If I delete the first `*ngIf="model"` everything is working fine. But I guess I'm having trouble with two ngIfs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a common problem when using `ngIf` in combination with `ViewChild`. You should be able to find a solution when searching for `ngIf ViewChild undefined`. For example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366981/viewchild-in-ngif

Comment: I tried that solution with using a setter. But this only works when I'm using a single *ngIf.
With two ngIfs my ViewChild results still as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from Angular 16 and trying to get an element that appears only after a user action. In my case I've used ngSwitch and ngIf. I couldn't solve it through ViewChild. But I managed to solve it quite easily like this:

1. setting the id on the required element:

> ```
> <input id="filter_add" matInput [(ngModel)]="filter" (ngModelChange)="onInputChange()" >
> ```

2. getting the element sometime when the element reaches the DOM:

> ```
> setTimeout(() => {
>     const inputRef = document.getElementById('filter_add');
>     inputRef.focus();
>  }, 100);
> ```

In this solution, the number of ngIfs or their nesting does not matter. You just have to work with the element while it exists.