# dynamic Template URL based on user role

Tags: angular

I just want to configure my dashboard according to the user role .

**for example**

1. if the user login have the role = admin , than the dashboard
   component should load the template URL which is for the admin.
2. similarly if the user login have the role = employee , than the
   dashboard component should load the template URL which is for the
   employee.

in short i am saying that i have one component namely dashboard , and i want to load three different template URLs at three different time on three different roles

Is it possible in angular 2 ? and how .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 can one component have multiple templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248159/angular-2-can-one-component-have-multiple-templates)

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to switch template URL at run time.

But you may try below for your use case,

```
<div [ngSwitch]="role">
   <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="admin">...</ng-template>
   <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="employee">...</ng-template>
</div>
```